# searching from different parameters

Tags: database, algorithm, search, logic

I have a database table `USER`, containing many fields like `firstName`, `lastName`, `rollNo`, `year`, `branch` etc.

In U.I, I have a text input control and a button to search user.
Now I want the users to be able to search anyone with any parameter, but how will I distinguish which parameter user has written in text input, I can't use multiple queries like:-

`Select * from User where firstName="sample"`

`Select * from User where lastName="sample"`

`Select * from User where rollNo="sample"`

Since this is a very inefficient method.

Neither can I ask user to specify which parameter they meant, since that is a very bad user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Select * from User where firstName="sample" Or lastName="sample" Or rollNo="sample"`